# How do I make a bash script become headless after the user has provided input

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ftp, wget

I'm trying to make a script become headless (the same way if I'd of run something with [nohup](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds4/nohup.htm)) after the user running the script has provided the `read` inputs.

Here is the script I'm using:

```
read -p "Please Input IP for FTP Server: " ip
read -p "Please Input FTP User: " ftpuser
read -p "Please Input FTP Password: " ftppasswd_u
read -p "Please Input The Patch Number You Wish To Download eg. 20180122: " FILE
read -p "Please Input Which Version Of TMFF You Are Downloading A Patch For eg. V191: " version

ftppasswd=${ftppasswd_u//@/%40}
#ftppasswd=$(sed 's/@/%40/' $ftppasswd_u)

echo "Downloading Patch " $FILE "from " $ip

wget -rnv ftp://$ftpuser:$ftppasswd@$ip/Patches/by_date/$FILE/weblogic
wget -rnv ftp://$ftpuser:$ftppasswd@$ip/Patches/by_date/$FILE/documentps
wget -rnv ftp://$ftpuser:$ftppasswd@$ip/Patches/by_date/$FILE/Readme.docx
```

To confirm, as soon as the user has provided all the read inputs I want the wget's to be headless (so the user can close their shell). Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The easiest way is:

```
nohup wget -rnv ftp://$ftpuser:$ftppasswd@$ip/Patches/by_date/$FILE/weblogic &
nohup wget -rnv ftp://$ftpuser:$ftppasswd@$ip/Patches/by_date/$FILE/documentps &
nohup wget -rnv ftp://$ftpuser:$ftppasswd@$ip/Patches/by_date/$FILE/Readme.docx &
```

This will let the `wget` run concurrently, which is probably OK.